# PulseAudio not detecting any devices

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

While using my laptop, at some point I noticed that my internal laptop microphone wouldn't work (but it was listed in Sound Settings -> Input) so I restarted my machine and then *poof* - PulseAudio detects no Output and no Input devices:

[image: PulseAudio Output]

[image]

I have no idea what caused this. I fail to remember doing anything abnormal prior to devices not being detected anymore.

How can I fix this?
`aplay -l` output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16 btw.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, pulseaudio only showed dummy devices, it stop showing my Intel audio devices after installing some packages.

So I followed these steps:
[The only device shown is "dummy output" or newly connected cards are not detected](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#The_only_device_shown_is_%22dummy_output%22_or_newly_connected_cards_are_not_detected)

To see which application is responsible for direct access to the sound card through alsa, run the following command:

```
sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*
```

In my case it was timidity-daemon:

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  root        659 f.... alsactl
                     timidity    762 F.... timidity
/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p:   timidity    762 F...m timidity
/dev/snd/seq:        timidity    762 F.... timidity
/dev/snd/timer:      timidity    762 f.... timidity
```

So i just uninstall the conflicting package and thats it.

Comment: This helped me after upgrading to (K)Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You made my day, I spent hours debugging this issue, and after all I simply removed timidity and it works as before

Comment: Upgrading to 20.04 caused it for me too, thanks for the help, the command `sudo apt install timidity-daemon` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You may have installed some (seemingly) innocuous audio program/daemon that takes control of the hardware before the user-space subsys is initialized. Had a similar issue after installing the 'sqeezelite' package but others can probably do the same thing or something equally troublesome; like using a different sound server target in their .conf or startup script.

These scenarios derive from
 - installing mixed gstreamer 0.10 & 1.00 libraries (recommend 0.10)
 - installing multiple sound server backends (such as PortAudio which has 'pa*' and '*-pa' named subsystems just like PulseAudio)
 - customized port-mappings in alsa (aconnectgui, hdajackretask, auto-configured, etc.)
 - zealous power-management settings
 - device proxies for virtual machine host pass-through devices
 - misconfigured 'media-key(s)' or other hardware issue

These are just some possible causes; your question gave little information (specifically, 'alsa' is installed and running) to for anyone to offer a specific solution. The information provided is based mostly on experience and just a bit of speculation (power management & media key issues). The screen caps don't mean much for folks using other X desktops or distros. The command 'aplay -l' does show that alsa is running but doesn't give the detail of:

### aplay -L

`default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=Intel
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, ALC889 Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions`
**-and-**

### lspci -b -vv

`00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GA-EP45-UD3R Motherboard
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 4 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 10
    Region 0: Memory at fdff8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable)
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=55mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee0300c  Data: 4172
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v1) Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0
            ExtTag- RBE-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        VC1:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=1 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=80
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [130 v1] Root Complex Link
        Desc:   PortNumber=0f ComponentID=02 EltType=Config
        Link0:  Desc:   TargetPort=00 TargetComponent=02 AssocRCRB- LinkType=MemMapped LinkValid+
            Addr:   00000000fed1c000
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel`

A very nice pulseaudio troubleshooting guide here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue on my Debian distro - Kali Linux. The solution here should also apply to Ubuntu systems. After installing Open Broadcasting Software and playing around with audio settings of `pavucontrol`, my volume up/down keys stopped responding. Going to settings, it offered only "Dummy" output as output device. Here's what worked for me (first two steps from [System76](https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/)):

1. Remove the configuration file of PulseAudio:

`rm -r ~/.config/pulse`

2. Kill all instances of PulseAudio

`pulseaudio -k`

3. Shut down (not restart) your system.
4. (May not be necessary but I did it anyway to flush my RAM memory just in case): Disconnect charger, then press and hold the power button or your PC/laptop for about 15-20 secs.
5. Power on your laptop and login
6. Open any audio player and play a song or something. You'll not hear any sound, and if you press your volume keys, you'd still see the "Dummy" control output.
7. Go to Sound settings: Settings > Sound
8. In the output section, you'll see "Dummy" selected as default output. Now clicking on the dropdown menu will give the option of "Speakers - Built-in-Audio".
9. Select it and your sound will come back alive with the volume keys responding again.
10. Worked for me :)